# ssrs - filter report with parameter. How to fill available values without overwriting default value of ALL?

Tags: report, reporting-services, before-filter, reportparameter

I have a "Area" parameter on a report and I want to provide filtering before running the report.

I have a extra dataset embedded in my report which calls for distinct areas and uses that to fill my drop down list for the parameter. This is what is set up under "Available Values". Under "Default Values" I have manually entered "ALL".

When I run my report I have my distinct areas and a "" default selection.

What have I done wrong? My intentions are to have the "ALL" option up top followed by each area numerically sorted ascending.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT DISTINCT area
FROM         ChuteXrefTbl
UNION
SELECT     'ALL' AS AvailableAreas

got me the choice of "ALL" in my dropdown list of available areas. Then I just had to set my report up to run a stored procedure and used a IF ELSE to see if the incoming area was "ALL".

This allows me to filter my report.

Right now the only thing I wish I could figure out is why "ALL" gets added at the bottom of the list despite whether you reverse the above sql syntax or not.

Answer (score 0):

Add Order By to the SQL clause and ALL will be re-ordered.

Another option is to set the parameter to "allow multiple values".  This will eliminate the need for the ALL item.